# Recognizing Horn clauses

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence, boolean-algebra

I am currently studying model theory and I am trying to decide if a clause is a Horn Clause. I know that a Horn Clause is a clause with at most one positive literal, but there are some clauses that it is not easy to decide whether they are Horn or not.

E.g.,

```
(P->Q)->W
```

Is there any way to decide whether this clause is Horn or not, or do I have to make further calculations in order to bring it to a Disjunction form?

Comment: $(P \to Q) \to W$ is not a clause, so in particular it's not a Horn clause.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus What I meant is that this can be transformed to a clause.. And then it may be a Horn clause. How can you know that by transforming this into CNF won't be a Horn Clause

Comment: If you eliminate the *implies*, you get $\lnot(\lnot P \vee Q) \vee W = (P \wedge \lnot Q) \vee W$, which is not a clause.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus can't this be considered as a literal (P∧¬Q)?

Comment: No, a literal is either a variable or a negation of a variable. A *clause* is a disjunction of literals. Your formula $(P\to Q)\to W$ is not a clause, and moreover it is not even *equivalent* to a clause. A formula is a Horn clause if it is equivalent to a clause in which at most one variable appears positively.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your effort and your time! I see now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start with some definitions:

1. A *literal* is either a variable (a *positive* literal) or the negation of a variable (a *negative* literal).
2. A *clause* is a formula which is equivalent to a disjunction of literals.
3. A *Horn clause* is a formula which is equivalent to a disjunction of literals, at most one of which is positive.

Your formula $(P \to Q) \to W$ is not equivalent to a disjunction of literals. Indeed, if it were, since it depends on all variables $P,Q,W$, it would have exactly one falsifying assignment (with respect to $P,Q,W$). Yet it has three: $(P,Q,W)=(F,F,F),(F,T,F),(T,T,F)$. So it is not a clause, and in particular not a Horn clause.